# Java: Trouble with TreeSet and LinkedList

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, comparator, treeset

I have an unsorted linked list. To sort it, I thought I'd put the values into a TreeSet with a comparator supplied, then return those values as a new linked list. Yet, it fails.

Comparator:

```
public class SortSpeciesByCommonName implements Comparator<Species> {

    /**
     * a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second. 
     */
    @Override
    public int compare(Species arg0, Species arg1) {
        return arg0.getName().compareTo(arg1.getName()); //arg.getName() is String
    }

}
```

Sorting function:

```
public static LinkedList<Species> sortedAnimals(LinkedList<Species> animals) {
    TreeSet<Species> sortedBreeds = new TreeSet<Species>(new SortSpeciesByCommonName());
    sortedBreeds.addAll(animals);
    return new LinkedList<Species>(sortedBreeds);
}
```

When testing the values, everything appears to still be in insertion order.

Comment: Please add the species class and some test cases. I've reduced the species class to just strings and everything works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you use [Collections.sort(List,Comparator)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)):

```
LinkedList<Species> sorted = new LinkedList<Species>(arg);
Collections.sort(sorted, new Comparator<Species>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Species s1, Species s2) {
      return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
  }
});
```

We cannot really debug your program and why the list isn't sorted.  Can you provide a test case?  What's the signature of `Species.getName()`?  Is it a `String`?

Comment: You should link to the overload that takes a `Comparator`. :-D

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you may find it easier to just use `Collections.sort`, passing in your list and comparator. Saves using a `TreeSet`.

Comment: Plus, the TreeSet could have the inadvertent side effect of eliminating items with duplicate names.